# Tunnel adapters on ipconfig?

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, network-adapter, ipconfig

Hello I recently noticed unusual information in my IPCONFIG. Usually I only see `Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection`, but now I see `Tunnel adapter isatap...` and `Tunnel adapter Teredo...` I was wondering if this is something I should be worried about, if yes how do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: Is the isaclient for MS ISA Proxy installed?

Comment: @PatrickSchneider I have no idea actually. How do I find out? Far as know I did not explicitly install any program named like that.

Comment: just take a look into the installed Software (appwiz.cpl) if there is an ms isa client or similiar. It seems that this tunnel adapter comes from the MS ISA Client which handles a transparent proxy for clients which use software that does not support advanced proyx settings.

Comment: @PatrickSchneider there doesn't appear to be any. here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/AMnJY.png

Comment: Arg i was wrong - sorry. ISATAP is used for IPv4 <-> IPV6 translation. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISATAP and here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=afe56282-2903-40f3-a5ba-a87bf92c096d &displaylang=en

Comment: @PatrickSchneider I see. So I probably got this through automatic Windows update?

Comment: Maybe you enabled ipv6 or something else. I have no specific information about this. For me the Adapter appears if i have contact to an ipv6 address.

Comment: Yeah I remember messing around with ipv6 sometime ago, I just don't remember seeing this in my ipconfig even though I do it quite regularly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both Teredo and ISATAP are mechanisms for IPv6 connectivity on IPv4-only networks. Since Windows 7 comes with IPv6 enabled, I wouldn't be surprised if they were *always* on, just didn't appear in `ipconfig` for some strange reason. (On one of my test VMs, the ISATAP adapter shows up, but not Teredo. Also strange.)

---

ISATAP is practically useless on a personal network, so it can be disabled permanently:

```
netsh interface ipv6 isatap set state disabled
```

On the other hand, Teredo works practically anywhere with the help of Microsoft's Teredo server – your screenshot has a global IPv6 address, too. You can leave it on, since Windows will always prefer native IPv4 over Teredo-tunneled (and possibly slower) IPv6 connections; but if you really want to get rid of it, apply the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set teredo disabled
```

Comment: I think I'll leave it. Just want to make sure they're safe and not connected to some kind of malware.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 is fully backward compatible with IPv4 without conflict. So ISATAP should always be enabled. Windows >7 Home Group networks are limited to only 20 systems, so unless your switch requires IPv6 it could be disabled without consequence (but nor is there a bennifit).