# How do I find the MAC Address of every networking of my notebook in win 8?

Tags: networking, cmd.exe, mac-address

I tried *getmac* command in command prompt. 
[image]

1. > What are those '3' devices of which the MAC Address is represented?

I Also Tried this Command: *ipconfig /all* [image][image]
Now,

2. > What are these "5" Mac Addresses here? Can anybody explain? How many Networking Devices are actually there in a Laptop?

Comment: Your laptop has wifi, Bluetooth and ethernet ports. The last two are virtual adapters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What are the '3' devices whose MAC Address is displayed?

`getmac /fo list /v` will display verbose output, which includes "Connection Name" and "Network Adapter"

Example output (from my PC):

```
f:\test>getmac /fo list /v

Connection Name:  Local Area Connection
Network Adapter:  Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Physical Address: F0-BF-97-62-95-5D
Transport Name:   Media disconnected

Connection Name:  Wireless Network Connection
Network Adapter:  [CommView] Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
Physical Address: CC-AF-78-B2-4C-09
Transport Name:   Media disconnected

Connection Name:  Bluetooth Network Connection
Network Adapter:  Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
Physical Address: CC-AF-78-B2-4C-0A
Transport Name:   Media disconnected

Connection Name:  Local Area Connection 2
Network Adapter:  Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device
Physical Address: 02-69-6E-66-12-61
Transport Name:   \Device\Tcpip_{37C93C8F-EE9C-4268-A33F-DD199D18748E}
```

`getmac` will only list physical adapters **not** virtual or tunnel adapters.

---

#### What are the '5' Mac Addresses here? Can anybody explain?

1. Virtual wireless connection (disconnected)
2. Bluetooth connection (disconnected) (also in the first list)
3. Wireless connection (active) (also in the first list)
4. Tunnel adapter isatap (disconnected)
5. Tunnel adapter Teredo

Tunnel adapters are used to implement IPv6 on an IPv4 network.

See [https://superuser.com/questions/417007/tunnel-adapters-on-ipconfig](https://superuser.com/a/417064/337631) answer by [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) for more information.

---

#### How many Networking Devices are actually there in a Laptop?

As many as it needs.

If you tether a mobile phone you will get another one (in my case it shows a second ethernet adapter but it's really a USB tethered mobile connection).

---

#### Further reading

[getmac](http://ss64.com/nt/getmac.html) - Display the Media Access Control (MAC) address and list of network protocols associated with each address for all network cards in each computer, either locally or across a network.

Comment: You Sir-- A Legend!